# CloudFront Block Access

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm testing out the CloudFront CDN but noticed that it will load the complete site.  Is there a way to only allow the CDN to serve request that start with /media/*  ?

I created a seperate behavior but won't let me delete the default one.

The other option is to provide a 404 from the website.  But I rather the CDN handle those request.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you are trying to do, but you could set the origin path to /media

Comment: the problem I run into with that is it then will make my request origin-domain.com/media now origin-domain.com/media/media

Comment: Thanks for leading me to a solution.  I ended up creating /cdn origin and then updated the code to respond correctly.